# How i can automaticcly turn on location?

Tags: java, android, gps, location

want to automatically turn on geolocation?

thanks all

[image: like this]

Comment: That would entirely defeat the purpose of the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to automatically turn on geolocation.

Sorry, but you can't.

The device belongs to the user, and you can only turn geolocation with the user's permission, as granted (or denied) by that prompt.

The best you can do is to display a message to the user telling them that your app cannot run unless they enable geolocation.  However, it is their choice to enable it, or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the user can't use the app until you get their location.